# How can I convert this C++ hash table to dynamically expand and shrink instead of having a hard-set max value?

Tags: c++

I found a hash table implementation online. It works by having a fixed limit of stored values, 200. No, In case I need more, I don't want to just increase the hard limit. Instead, is there a way to make it dynamically expand to hold more values?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;
class HashTableEntry {
   public:
      int k;
      int v;
      HashTableEntry(int k, int v) {
         this->k= k;
         this->v = v;
      }
};
class HashMapTable {
   private:
      HashTableEntry **t;
      unsigned int t_s;
   public:
      HashMapTable() {
         t = new HashTableEntry * [t_s];
         t_s = 200;
         for (int i = 0; i< t_s; i++) {
            t[i] = NULL;
         }
      }
      int HashFunc(int k) {
         return k % t_s;
      }
      void Insert(int k, int v) {
         int h = HashFunc(k);
         while (t[h] != NULL && t[h]->k != k) {
            h = HashFunc(h + 1);
         }
         if (t[h] != NULL)
            delete t[h];
         t[h] = new HashTableEntry(k, v);
      }
      int SearchKey(int k) {
         int h = HashFunc(k);
         while (t[h] != NULL && t[h]->k != k) {
            h = HashFunc(h + 1);
         }
         if (t[h] == NULL)
            return -1;
         else
            return t[h]->v;
      }
      void Remove(int k) {
         int h = HashFunc(k);
         while (t[h] != NULL) {
            if (t[h]->k == k)
               break;
            h = HashFunc(h + 1);
         }
         if (t[h] == NULL) {
            cout<<"No Element found at key "<<k<<endl;
            return;
         } else {
            delete t[h];
         }
         cout<<"Element Deleted"<<endl;
      }
      ~HashMapTable() {
         for (int i = 0; i < t_s; i++) {
            if (t[i] != NULL)
               delete t[i];
               delete[] t;
         }
      }
};
```

The issue is if I use `realloc` or something and increase and decrease `t_s` it might change the keys in which values are stored, and break the hash table. Another issue is, when it has no items stored `t_s` would be 0, and in `hashFunc`, remainder by 0 is undefined. How would I handle these problems? How would I create a dynamically increasing and shrinking hash table in C++?

Comment: You're asking multiple questions that likely expand to a significant rewrite of this code.

Comment: *I found a hash table implementation online.* -- I did too.  It's called [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Comment: It is bug ridden.  I could write a two line program using what you've posted, and the program will fall apart. `int main() { HashMapTable h1; HashMapTable h2 = h1;}`  -- This is even after you fix the error pointed out by @FelixDombek

Comment: @PounddefineMACRO It was Felix who said that - and I agree. Read his comment and you can verify by reading the code that what he said is correct.

Comment: @PounddefineMACRO unless you are coding a hash table yourself as an exercise, or really anything already available in the C++ standard libraries, you should always use the ones available in the C++ standard libraries. If you want to use anything else make sure they come from tried and tested libraries such as [abseil](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp) or [folly](https://github.com/facebook/folly) to name a few.

Comment: 200 is bad number of bins. Better to use a prime number of bins to reduce hash collisions.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The code in that link isn't even valid C++. `clang++` refuses to compile it.

Comment: @PounddefineMACRO Why do you want a hash table? Practice? Or you need one for something specific? You do know there is one in the standard library?

Comment: @MartinYork I want to store key-value pairs where the keys are arbitrary and don't have to be numbers, and retrieve them quickly. I want to simulate, for example, indexing a table/array with a string, in C++. I need to retrieve values associated with arbitrary numbers. Using a plain array wouldn't work, because then the numbers would have to fall in the array bounds.

Comment: @PounddefineMACRO You know there are several containers in the standard libraries that would satisfy those requirements.

Comment: @MartinYork WHich is the best one

Comment: Look at: `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` they both provide what you request. They have slightly different charateristics. `std::map` has O(log(n)) insert/find etc while `std::unordered_map` has O(1) insert/find etc.

Comment: @MartinYork Which one is the better choice `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`? Which one has less muck/which one is more efficient for my requirements?

Comment: @PounddefineMACRO you requirements are very vague. The only way to know that is to write test specific to your situation and try both.

Comment: @MartinYork I just need to store values associated with numbers. Like `Array[1000] = 10` without needing to allocate all the memory in between.

Comment: @PounddefineMACRO Try `std::map<int, int>` that will work and has good all-around characteristics.

Comment: @PounddefineMACRO if you only need dictionary lookup then both `std::unordered_map` or `std::map` should suffice. You can choose the one which is shorter to type :)

Comment: @PounddefineMACRO Since you want an hash, `std::unordered_map` would be a better fit. If you prefer sorted items, a map would be a the choice. In your case, they would probably works equally well.

Answer (score 2):

Typically people who are running "batch computations" (not with any real-time sensitivity) will just take the hit and create a copy with a larger size, then swap it in.

There are methods to incrementally grow a hash table so that you can still have O(1) access while growing but the constant hidden in the O(1) grows larger for all accesses and they're tricky to get right.

A different suggestion to have incremental growth while retaining O(1) access is to have a "stack" of hash tables - start with, say a 200 entry hash table, then when that reaches its fill limit (0.7 or 0.8 full, whatever you choose) push a 400 entry hash table on the stack and put new entries in it.  Each time the top of the stack gets full push another empty double-size hash table on it.  Add items only to the top of the stack.  But you must search all stack elements (each hash table) on access before deciding that the item is missing.  So your O(1) access grows - but this is a simpler scheme to get right.